# What statistic test to use to measure difference between samples from the same person?

Tags: t-test, descriptive-statistics

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

I want for each person, to check how statistically significant the difference between the means of the two weekdays is. In my current implementation I am conducting a student's t-test. Are there other statistical tests that can help me here? I am worried because we are talking about the same person and not about two different populations and I can not find any info on how to handle that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming data are normal:** For each person you would use a *2-sample* t test
to compare Day 1 and Day 3 (not a paired test, see @SalMangiafico's Comment). In your question, for subject A you show only
three observations on each day. With so little data on any one person (and such large within-day
variability) you will have trouble getting significant results.

For the data in your question, rounded to three places, the P-value is
much larger than 0.05, so you cannot reject $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_3$ in favor of $H_a: \mu_1 \ne \mu_3$ at the 5% level of significance. A two-sample t test in R follows:

```
A1 = c(.692, .198, .489);  A3 = c(.091, .446, .513)
t.test(A1, A3)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  A1 and A3
t = 0.56484, df = 3.9676, p-value = 0.6026
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  -0.4311325  0.6504658
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
0.4596667 0.3500000
```

**Not assuming normal data:** With so little data, there is no point in testing for normality (or for any other
particular population distribution). In case you believe data are not normal, you might use a Wilcoxon rank sum test. But such a test would require at least four measurements per person per day in order to have any chance of giving a
significant result. (Even if all three measurements on one of the days are larger than any of the three measurements on the other day, you still could not possibly get a significant result at the 5% level: $2/{6 \choose 3} = 2/20 = 0.10.)$

```
B1 = c(.20, .30, .40);  B3 = c(.13, .02, .18)  # fake data for illustration
wilcox.test(B1, B3)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  B1 and B3
W = 9, p-value = 0.1
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer! I have already figured that the data is not enough to produce results using a 95% confidence interval. Luckily, the usage is such that there is no reason to use such a strict confidence interval. I can probably go with 85% without a problem since false positives are not a problem in the use case.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you did a paired t-test. You could also look at two way ANOVA. But please go through the specifications to further understand if your experiment aligns to the requisites.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, I conducted a paired t-test. Will look into a two way ANOVA as well.

Comment: If you have multiple days, you want to look at a repeated measures ANOVA.

Comment: The question talks about comparing days within each person. I don't see how a paired t-test is applicable here.

Comment: Test would have to be carried out for each person.

Comment: By what criteron would you then pair the observations?

Comment: Using the weekday column